Benders Decomposition Implementation - Should I keep the old feasibility cut in master problem?
I am currently working on combinatorial subproblems. First, I need to solve the master problem, find all possible subproblems, solve each combination individually, and ensure all the subproblems are feasible.
My question is, should I keep all the old cuts in the master problem as constraints, for example, if I solved the first combination but it is not feasible, then the cut is added to the master problem, but still, the problem is not feasible however the value is converging to tolerance value, so, should I keep that cut as a constraint?

Yes, generally you need to keep the old feasibility cuts in the master program in succeeding iterations. Otherwise, you may simply reproduce the master-solutions, that lead to infeasible subproblems later on.
That said, sometimes it can be a good idea to thin-up your list of cuts if you end up with too many constraints in the master program (here, too many means that the master program becomes too slow to solve). Its a bit of an art to decide on which cuts to remove, as it is not sufficient to check if a cut is binding or not in a solution to the master program. Hence, you need to experiment if you go down that road.
From your question, it seems you are implementing an "old-fashioned" version of Benders' decomposition. You may want to read up on modern Benders'. A good introductory source can be found here: https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/10/benders-decomposition-then-and-now.html

Actually, I would now consider using lazy constraints to be the old-fashioned way. The modern way would be to solve the MILP up to a reasonable solution (instead of solving it to optimality). Nowadays, MILP solvers are often able to find very good solutions very quickly. That's for example what SHOT is doing

@fontanf when you say “solve the MILP up to a reasonable solution”, do you mean the original MILP prior to reformulating it, or do you mean solving the Benders’ master program a limited number of times?

I mean solving the Benders' master program

@fontanf Are you proposing a "one tree" solution, but delaying subproblem solutions until a "good" master candidate is found (as opposed to trying the subproblems each time a candidate is identified), or are you going back to the original Benders approach where you restart the modified master problem from the root node after adding cuts (only with the master stopped short of optimality)?

@prubin Back to the original Benders approach, but not necessarily wait for proven optimality of the master problem. MILP solvers themselves implement restarting strategies.

@fontanf this sounds like a ``matheuristic'' version of Benders' decomposition. Or do you still consider your suggestion as an exact method, by for example requiring an optimal solution for the master program when the algorithm sees $UB-master_value<\varepsilon$?

To get an optimality proof, one has to solve the master to optimality at the end. It's just not required to solve all master problems to optimality.

I agree that the approach suggested by @fontanf would work. Compared to the one tree (callback) approach, it's a question of which wastes more time - one-tree generating cuts for candidate solutions not near optimality or Benders with suboptimal solutions where restarts go back to the root node (albeit with cuts added). My guess is that, on any given problem, either might beat the other.
